# connect client side java program to access database

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, ms-access

I am making a practice program using java and an access database.
the program is an ultimate tictactoe board and the databse is meant for keeping track of the names of the players and their scores.
the trouble i am having is that i keep getting these errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AccessDatabaseConnection.getName(AccessDatabaseConnection.java:39)
at ultimate.<init>(ultimate.java:39)
at ultimate.main(ultimate.java:82)
```

with further research i also found this:
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

here is my code. the math is a little unfinished in the sql statements but im not really worried about that yet. i need to get this connection between the program and the database.

here is the area of code in my constructor for the program that connects to the accessdatabaseconnections class:

```
  AccessDatabaseConnection DB = new AccessDatabaseConnection();

  Font f = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 80);

  public ultimate() {
    super("Testing Buttons");

    String dbname = DB.getName();
    String wins = DB.getWins();
    String losses = DB.getLosses();

    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(null);
    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {// set the rows
        x = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {// set the columns
            button[j][i] = new JButton();
            container.add(button[j][i]);
            button[j][i].setName(Integer.toString(j) + "_"
                    + Integer.toString(i));
            button[j][i].addActionListener(handler);
            button[j][i].setSize(100, 100);
            button[j][i].setVisible(true);
            button[j][i].setFont(f);
            button[j][i].setText(null);
            if ((i > 2 && j < 3 && i < 6) || (j > 2 && j < 6 && i  < 3)
                    || (j > 2 && j < 6 && i < 9 && i > 5)
                    || (j > 5 && j < 9 && i < 6 && i > 2)) {
                button[j][i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            } else {
                button[j][i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            button[j][i].setLocation(x, y);
            x = x + 110;

        }

        y = y + 110;
    }
    setSize(1024, 1050);
    setVisible(true);
    container.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ultimate application = new ultimate();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    PlayerOne = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 1: Enter Your Name");
    PlayerTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 2: Enter Your Name");

    while(PlayerOne == PlayerTwo){
        PlayerTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 2: Re-Enter Your Name (Cannot be the same!)");
    }
}
```

and here is the code for accessing the database:

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 public class AccessDatabaseConnection {

public static Connection connect() {
    Connection con;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver{Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\McKenzieC\\Documents\\tictactoeRecords.accdb;";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return con;
}

public void addData(String nameOne, int win, String nameTwo,int loss){
    try {
    Statement stmt = connect().createStatement();
    stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO t_Records (Name, Wins) " +
            "VALUES (" + nameOne + ", " + Integer.toString(win));

    /*stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO t_Records (Name, Wins) " +
            "VALUES (" + nameTwo + ", " + Integer.toString(loss));
     + ", " + Integer.toString(loss)*/
    }
 catch (SQLException ex) {
}
}

public String getName() {
    try {
        Statement stmt = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t_Records");
        if (rset.next()) {
            String name = rset.getString("Name");
            return name;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String getWins() {
    try {
        Statement stmt = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t_Records");
        if (rset.next()) {
            String wins = rset.getString("Wins");
            return wins;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String getLosses() {
    try {
        Statement stmt = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t_Records");
        if (rset.next()) {
            String losses = rset.getString("Losses");
            return losses;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

}

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit JVM?  http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you can't see the real error because you're hiding the real error:

Never do this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    return null;
}
```

You can change for this at least (again not recommended but better than the above code):

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
//After this change the program will fail again but you will got a better error message
```

But you always must manage the Exception:

- Print a error message
- Put a log message (java logging, log4j and so on)
- Deal with the error
- Re-throw the exception
- And son on

Answer (score 1):

The statement...

```
String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver{Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\McKenzieC\\Documents\\tictactoeRecords.accdb;";
```

...has two problems:

1. You are missing the equal sign (`=`) after the `Driver` keyword.
2. There is no ODBC driver named `Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)`.

Try this instead:

```
String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\McKenzieC\\Documents\\tictactoeRecords.accdb;";
```

Comment: thank you. the error seems to go away after that little adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Statement stmt` equal null after `connect().createStatement();`? If yes, then `stmt.executeQuery` will cause null ptr exception.

Comment: it was null because the connection to the database was also null.

Comment: actually no, it was null because you returned null from connect method.